# graphing 3 dimensional space

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> In each part, describe the graph of the function in an xyz-coordinate system.
> $f(x, y) = 1 − x − \frac{1}{2} y$

As you can see there's no $z$ axis. But, when I had looked at the answer. The graph was looking like this

[image]

I was asking the question cause, in "question" there's no $z$ axis. Than, why $z$ axis in graph isn't always 0. I had looked at the graph more deeply. What I understand from that graph that is $f(x,y)$ is $z$ axis. So, now my question is what does the function ( $f(x,y,z)=z − x − \frac{1}{2} y$ ) represent? So, $f(x,y,z)$ is actually another axis (Time), isn't it? I think I misunderstood lot of things.

Comment: The idea is that the input is a value in $n$ space and is an ordered tuple of $n$ numeric real values.  the value of $f(x_1,....,x_n)$ is a real value, $x_{n+1}$ and we draw it as an $n+1$ axis in a $n+1$ space.  Thus we write a function on one space as $y = f(x) = 1+ x^2$.  And we write a function on two space as $z = f(x,y) = 1-x - \frac 12 y$.  And in three space as $w = f(x,y,z) = z -x - \frac 12 y$ and on four space $v = f(x,y,z,w) = w^3 - (y+x)^2 -\frac 1z$ (or whatever).  And so on.  Of course we have limitations on how to *DRAW* this in the 2-d paper or even 3-D universe.  ... tbc...

Comment: @fleablood You had used $\omega$ for 4D. and, $\nu$ (maybe, you used $v$) for 5D. Why you did? Actually, you wrote them as sample. Or, they have meaning? I had never seen these for higher dimensional graph

Comment: Now the fourth, fifth, sixth, three thousand and twentyseventh dimension don't need to be time or anything *physical* (*ugh*.... physical reality.... utterly irrelevant and ... distasteful... to the abstract mathematician) unless we are specifically discussing a function of *position* in the physical world.  As a function can be of *any* concern of variable.  ($x$ be the number of bananas, $y$ be the number of people working, $z$ but money, $w$ be motor oil, $v$ but the energy termites exhaust during sex,. $u$ be....) the idea of "Gee, what is the *fifth* dimension" doesn't matter...

Comment: Why did I use $w$ and $v$?  Why not?  I had to use *something*.   They seemed a reasonable choice.   There's nothing *meaningful* about the labels we use and there's nothing about *physical space* in setting up a problem.  It's just that to *DRAW* a picture you need several axis... unfortunately we are bound by the physical universe we draw it in.  Fortunately graphs aren't that important and we can often content ourselves with just cross sections.  But sometimes it is frustrating.  You just *can't* draw $f(x,y,z) = z - x - \frac 12 y$.